# How can I filter() stream method using regexp and predicate to get negated list

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am trying to filter anything not in the regexp.
So what I am trying to express is write anything to a list that has characters other than a-z,0-9 and -, so I can deal with these city names with invalid characters afterwards.
But whatever I try I either end up with a list of valid cities or an IllegalArgumentException where the list contains valid character cities.

```
 String str;

    List<String> invalidCharactersList = cityName.stream()
            .filter(Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9-]*$").asPredicate())
            .collect(toList());

    // Check for invalid names
    if (!invalidCharactersList.isEmpty()) {
        str = (inOut) ? "c" : "q";
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("City name characters "
                + str + ": for city name " + invalidCharactersList.get(0)
                + ": fails constraint city names [a-z, 0-9, -]");
    }
```

I am try to filter anything not in the regexp

Following is some test data which fails on the first list, I want it to fail on last

```
List<String> c = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("fastcity", "bigbanana", "xyz"));
List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(23, 23, 23));
List<Integer> y = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 10, 20));
List<String> q = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("fastcity*", "bigbanana", "xyz&"));
```

Following is output:

[image]

Comment: `.filter(Pattern.compile("^[a-z0-9-]+$").asPredicate().negate())`

Comment: There’s no sense in trying to find invalid characters in a `List<Integer>`. Further, reporting the first list element when an arbitrary element fails the test, can be very confusing. Besides that, it’s as easy as `filter(Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9-]").asPredicate())`; this will pass when any character other than a-z,0-9 and - exists.

Comment: _I want it to fail on last_ What do you mean by "you want it to fail"? You are filtering a `List`. You want certain `List` elements filtered out, right? So after filtering the last `List` the filtered `List` will contain only one element, namely _bigbanana_. Is that right?

Comment: @Abra I wanted the list to just contain xyz& as & is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Holger

```
filter(Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9-]").asPredicate())
```

Thanks this works fine.

Comment: Don't want to nitpick this but for an input of `fastcity\nbigbanana\nxyz\nfastcity*\nbigbanana\nxyz&` and `^[a-z0-9-]+$` as regex, it takes 36 steps while `[^a-z0-9-]` completes in 55 steps.

Comment: @Aniket Sahrawat Out of curiousity how did you work out the steps? Did you run it through debug or use a profiler?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat your comment makes no sense. Are you really talking about an input with line breaks, what is a “step”, and how did you measure?

Comment: With [this test program](https://ideone.com/JNjjNm), you can see that `[^a-z0-9-]` needs *less* operations. Since the test program prints the characters read by the engine, you can also see why. The pattern `^[a-z0-9-]+$` will try to match the anchor and backtrack when encountering  an invalid character. You can eliminate the backtracking using `^[a-z0-9-]++$` which will shorten the gap, but there’s still one access for the anchor test at the invalid character. But for any practical purpose, there is no relevant difference between the two approaches.

Comment: @Holger Output of your program with [Java 11](https://imgur.com/a/d0NcDNT) and with [java 16](https://imgur.com/a/2LC4DQc). There is a clear difference but even you know that it is not a standard way. I originally tested it on PCRE. Anyways, I won't argue on this further as you already mentioned in the last sentence of your second comment.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I don’t know of a “standard way” to check this and provided a method that tests what the engine is really doing. Anyway, that seems to be an interesting performance regression with JDK 16 that I’ll investigate (and perhaps file a bug report).